# Calculating walking distance from train stations in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, network-analyst

I am trying to find a way to make a buffer(?) around the train stations which follows the roads nearby. My thought is to make a visualization of how far from the trainstation you can get in 5, 10 and 15 minutes from the stations in normal walking pace - when following the roads.

Do anyone know how or if this can be done? I have managed to create a buffer with a linear value.

[image: A snippet from my project window showing downtown Oslo]

I am using the dataset called "Kartdata_Norge_UTM33_N50_FGDB" from kartverket (Norwegian mapping authority) in ArcMap 10.3.

The Network Analyst extension and license are installed.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is what is referred to as a network service area. You need the Network Analyst extension installed and licensed to be able to use this functionality. Look at this [help page](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/types-of-network-analyses.htm) to discover the types of analyses you can run.

Comment: The Network Analyst extension and license are installed